# Invoke action after primefaces fileDownload completed (delete temp file)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.2 app, my business-logic requires that --- when a user downloads a file -- I pack several file into a temporary zip file which is then streamed to the user. Now I fail to delete (clean up) the temporary file after a sucessful download.

I tried to invoke the delete of the files as follows:

view:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['common.actions.download']}"
    ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);"
    icon="fa fa-download">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{kundeController.getFile(file)}" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:remoteCommand name="stop" oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"
                    actionListener="#{customerController.downloadFinished()}">
</p:remoteCommand>
```

the relevant methods from my view-scoped bean (CustomerController):

```
public StreamedContent getFile(FileDto fileToLoad) {
    selectedFile = fileToLoad;
    try {
        tmpFilePath = fileService.getFilePath(fileToLoad);

        fis = new FileInputStream(tmpFilePath.toFile());
        sreamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(fis, "", fileToLoad.getOriginalFilename);

        return sreamedContent;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        showMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "download.generic.error", "", null);
        logger.error("Problem to load {}", fileToLoad.getPfad(), e);
        throw new AbortProcessingException();
    }

}

public void downloadFinished() {
    logger.info("Download finished");
    try {
        logger.info("attempting to delete {}", tmpFilePath.toString());
        sreamedContent.getStream().close();
        Files.deleteIfExists(tmpFilePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("error while deleting temp-file", e);
    }
    logger.info("deleted temp-file");
}
```

The temporary file is created in the method `fileService.getFilePath(FileDto fileToLoad)` using the method `java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(String filename)`.

It seems that the remote-command "stop" is invoked before the entire file has been downloaded: The download gets interrupted as soon as I close the stream.

```
11:13:28.690 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  myApp.controller.CustomerController - attempting to delete C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_420062840599424196.zip
Jan 12, 2016 11:13:28 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:90)
```

What is the correct way to invoke an action after the download is finished?

Comment: I think you should try putting `downloadFinished` on a different form cuz when file is downloaded then stop called then `p:remoteCommand` called that would fire form submit may cause download file to fire again and in the same time got interruptted  by `downloadFinished` method.

Comment: @YouYou it's not working...

Comment: Do you have a successful file downloaded or corrupted one ?

Comment: the file is corrupted

Comment: Did you analyze what downloadMonitor does? Maybe it helps to also create a 'start' function or check for cookie blocking